# Background thread executed event after foreground thread exited?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I was going through Microsoft docs for `ThreadPool` and they explained that `ThreadPool` threads are background threads which do not keep the application running if all foreground threads have terminated.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void Main()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc);
    Console.WriteLine("From main foreground thread");
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Console.WriteLine("Exiting from main");
}

static void ThreadProc(object stateInfo) {
    Console.WriteLine("From the thread pool");
}
```

With `Thread.Sleep(1000)` uncommented it is sure that the background thread will complete before the main foreground thread exits. But when we comment the sleep part then also I get an output of sort:

```
From main foreground thread
Exiting from main
From the thread pool
```

It means that the background thread is still executed even when the main foreground thread has exited. Why so?

Comment: It is a classic threading race bug.  Stuff *does* happen after that Console.WriteLine() call and before the CLR can terminate the program.  Very little is needed, in all likelihood that threadpool thread is blocking on a mutex that prevents output to the console getting mixed up.  So it takes but a handful of nanoseconds to get its turn.  Runs in unmanaged code as well that the CLR can't abort until it completes.

Comment: +1. In your current code just put `Thread.Sleep(1000);` before `Console.WriteLine("From the thread pool");` and see it is no more displayed.

Comment: Never, never fix a threading race bug with Sleep().

Comment: My comment is not about fixing race, it's about showing the program does not wait for a thread from the pool to finish.

Answer (score 0):

The end of the Main method doesn't mean the "foreground" thread has exited.  Even if it has, it doesn't mean your process has terminated.

Normally, a process stops when all threads that run in the process (including the ones from the thread-pool, which have queued work) terminate.  However, if you exit a process using [ExitProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess).   The CLR works in a slighly more complicated way ([see here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cbrumme/startup-shutdown-and-related-matters/)), which does quite some clean-up before really existing the application.

As a result, before all working threads get killed, there is pretty some time when work can get done.

Comment: So all the threads (including background threads) should be terminated. By terminated we mean either killed or executed within the time process actually exits. Am i right?

Comment: Thread-pool threads are background threads, and as such [they do not keep the program running](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads). Once all foreground threads have been stopped, the system stops all background threads and shuts down.

Comment: Don't forget that shutting down the app takes time, which background threads can use.